# Can not delete child entity of OneToMany relationship with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I can't delete an child entity (SolicitudArxiu) with parent (Solicitud) defined as Cascade as we can see under.

It seems that the definition of the relationship in the parent(cascade) entity affects to deletion from child, because when I remove the cascade then the deletion works.

Is there a form to force deletion of a child (SolicitudArxiu)?

**SolicitudArxiuManager(child entity to delete)**

```
public void delete(int id) {
    try {
        SolicitudArxiu reference = this.em.getReference(SolicitudArxiu.class, id);
        this.em.remove(reference);
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        //we want to remove it
        logger.error("Entity not found exeption: ", e);
    }
}
```

**Solicitud (parent entity)**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_solicitud")
public class Solicitud implements Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "solicitud", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<SolicitudArxiu> sarxius;
   ...
```

**SolicitudArxiu.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "r_solicitudArxiu",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"idSolicitud","idArxiu"}))
public class SolicitudArxiu implements Serializable {
...
    @ManyToOne
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idSolicitud", referencedColumnName = "id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "solicitudArxiu2solicitud"))
    private Solicitud solicitud;

    @ManyToOne
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idArxiu", referencedColumnName = "id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "solicitudArxiu2arxiu"))
    private Arxiu arxiu;
   ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you cannot delete the entity without removing the relation from the owning side, so first remove the relation then remove your child.

Comment: It's what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to delete the relationship between t_solicitud and t_arxiu, but after execute em.remove, the entity remains there.  ¿?

Comment: if you are using jpa 2.0 or higher when removing the entity the child will remain unless you define the orphanRemoval to be true, so either you remove the relation then the entity or define the orphanRemoval to be true so when the relation is removed the child will be removed

Comment: @Joe I just noticed you already have the orphanRemoval set, then removing the relation will be enough to remove the child

Comment: But it still does not work, I called the delete method above but it doesn't remove the solicitudArxiu entity. No idea what it is.

Comment: can you share SolicitudArxiu  class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153671/discussion-between-amer-qarabsa-and-joe).

Comment: Given the relationship is owned by the child side (`SolicitudArxiu`), I suspect you may need to clear out the relationship on `SolicitudArxiu` to break the relationship.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I don't want to save the complete object Solicitud, because in case of cancel the edition the only to save it will be the  files(arxiu) not the rest of fields, and saving the object all the modifications will be persisted ¿?. In case they save the entity there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to do it the easy way with a createNativeQuery, and avoid the restrictions of JPA relationship.

```
em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM r_solicitudArxiu WHERE id = ?")
   .setParameter(1, id)
   .executeUpdate();
```